# final static vs static final variables

Tags: java, static, final

I have the following compiling code:

```
final static String test = "A";
static final String test2 = "B";
```

And everything compiles fine. My question is, what is the difference between these two?

Comment: They are exactly the same. 

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219556/difference-between-final-static-and-static-final

Comment: In short, they can be used in either order, there is no technical difference as several other answers here and referenced by the specified links state.

Comment: static final is preferred according to JLS!

Answer (score 12):

[The order of those modifiers isn't mandatory, as stated in the Java Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1) :

> FieldModifiers:
>       FieldModifier
>       FieldModifiers FieldModifier
>
> FieldModifier: one of
>       Annotation public protected private
>       static final transient volatile

But please note that the Java Specification introduces a best practice :

> If two or more (distinct) field modifiers appear in a field
>   declaration, it is customary, though not required, that they appear in
>   the order consistent with that shown above in the production for
>   FieldModifier.

Which means that the most correct solution is

```
static final String test2 = "B";
```

The fact most coders respect this "custom" means that their fellow coders parse and read the code faster and with greater ease.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. The order you put the keywords in doesn't matter.