# The difference between final static and static final

Tags: java

Is there any difference between the two following statements in `Java`?

1. `public static final String STOP= "STOP";`
2. `public final static String STOP= "STOP";`

Comment: The difference doesn't extend beyond the difference in the text you have posted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between final static and static final](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219556/difference-between-final-static-and-static-final)

Comment: static final is preferred according to JLS!

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference other than the visual appearance.  They are equivalent.  However, it is recommended to just choose one.  The [language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1) recommends `public static final` over `public final static`, however.

Answer (score 4):

The order of modifier keywords does not matter.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between the two.

According to [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1):

> If two or more (distinct) field modifiers appear in a field
>   declaration, it is customary, though not required, that they appear in
>   the order consistent with that shown above in the production for
>   FieldModifier.